# How to use "IF" code with multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have 5 columns of data with around 50,000 rows. This is the ambulance response times to an incident. I am trying to figure out the total number of incidents as multiple ambulances respond to a single incident. The 'IF' function has been useful upto a certain extent where the multiple ambulances reached at the same time but when it is not at the same time, it considers it as a different incident. I would like to add a buffer of 20 minutes but I am not able to figure out how to incorporate that. The second problem is with the incident number. The incidents 2014-014374-006, 2014-014374-009 are the same, just the ending numbers are different. How do I differentiate? Can I do it in excel or other platforms?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Hzp.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return the incident number, use a formula like this: "=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("-",D5,SEARCH("-",D5)+1)),D5,LEFT(D5,SEARCH("-",D5,SEARCH("-",D5)+1)-1))" where D5 is the cell with your incident number.

What this formula does is it first creates an if statement that will allow you to determine if the incident has the second dash or if it doesnt. If it doesn't, then it will return the value in the cell. If it does, it will return the text to the left of that dash. The search function looks for a substring, and by nesting a search and adding "1" to the value of the first search, we are looking for the substring that comes after the first one is found.

It is a rather confusing formula the first time you use it, but it works like a charm once you understand it.

I will see if I can figure the dates out. That might be more difficult. If you can simply use the incident number for this, you will likely have an easier time.

Comment: that worked to an extent. So, in the 50,000 rows, incidents with dashes are around 2000, it worked for them. There are some with no dashes but prefix is the same and suffix are alphabets. (03217A, 03217B). I am trying to figure this out, but the biggest pain is the time buffer, if i can add + 15 minutes to unit notified, that would solve most of the problem. Is there a way to separate the unit notified column in to two columns, with date in one and time in the other?

Comment: Add two columns next to your date column. In the first one set it to =MOD(D6, 1) where D6 is your date value. Format this column as time values. For your second column set it equal to your original date - your time column.

Comment: Also, with the columns where the formula doesnt work, what does it return?

Comment: I separated the time column, now I need to add a 15 minute buffer to my IF statement. The columns where the formula doesn't work, it returns incident as 1 as compared to 0 (being the same incident). I used my original code =IF(A5<>A4,"1",IF(B5<>B4,"1",IF(E5<>E4,"1","0")))

Comment: I dont know how to write the IF formula off the top of my head, but to add 15 minutes use "+.01" and to subtract use "-.01"

Comment: So I separated out the time column which reads 3:37:00 PM, 1:10:00 PM etc. Now if i try to edit the last segment of the IF statement to IF(R2<=R1+".01","0","1")))), it returns the same answer as before. It does not consider the 15 minute time buffer. Can I add + or - in the formula?

Comment: Try putting the two items you are adding together into their own set of parenthesis, this may help. Otherwise I would have to test it on my end later.

Comment: Its giving me the same result, tried a few different variations.

Comment: Did you test it on your end Brandon?

Comment: This formula works on my end when I tested it briefly. It checks whether the value being tested is less than or greater than the time above it by 15 minutes. Here you go: "=IF(OR(G3<=(G2-0.01), G3<=(G2+0.01)), 1, 0)"